# How to extract contours from HFS segmented image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

How to grab contours from HFS model output?
I'm trying to detect floor. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: HFS_OUTPUT]

Comment: Can you clarify expected output? Largest segment inside ROI? extract segment which contains a point specified by user?

Comment: Your question is not completely clear, on what the "floor" means. This could be interpreted to mean that you want the bounding box of the floor or the binary segmented mask. If you want the mask, one approach is to use `cv2.inRange()` and color threshold to segment the peach color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the floor has a specific color range, we can color threshold using `cv2.inRange()`. We convert the image to HSV format then use a lower and upper threshold to generate a binary segmented mask

```
lower = np.array([0, 31, 182])
upper = np.array([57, 75, 209])
```

[image]
[image]

To find the floor contour, we can just find contours on the mask image. Here's the result with the floor highlighted in green

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Color threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 31, 182])
upper = np.array([57, 75, 209])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original,original,mask=mask)

# Find floor contour on mask
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(original,[c], -1, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```