# How to detect a rectangle (whiteboard) in an image using opencv?

Tags: python, image, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have the following image. I want to detect and perspective transform the rectangular whiteboard.

[image]

I want to detect these 4 boundaries/corners and apply a perspective transformation to it. Have a look at the below image:

[image]

I am not able to detect the boundaries of the rectangle. Here's what I have tried:

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow


image = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
orig1 = image.copy()
# 1) Grayscale image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# cv2_imshow(gray)
# 2) Erosion
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations = 1)
# cv2_imshow(erosion)

# 3) Thresholding (OTSU)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(erosion, (5,5),0)
ret3, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# cv2_imshow(thresh)

# 4) Contours
copy = thresh; orig = image; 
cnts = cv2.findContours(copy, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
area = -1; c1 = 0
for c in cnts:
    if area < cv2.contourArea(c):
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        c1 = c
cv2.drawContours(orig,[c1], 0, (0,255,0), 3)    

epsilon = 0.09 * cv2.arcLength(c1,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c1,epsilon,True)

if len(approx) != 4:
    # Then it will fail here.
    pass 
cood = []
for i in range(0, len(approx)):
    cood.append([approx[i][0][0], approx[i][0][1]])

# 5) Perspective Transformation
def reorder(myPoints):
    myPoints = np.array(myPoints).reshape((4, 2))
    myPointsNew = np.zeros((4, 1, 2), dtype=np.int32)
    add = myPoints.sum(1)
    myPointsNew[0] = myPoints[np.argmin(add)]
    myPointsNew[3] =myPoints[np.argmax(add)]
    diff = np.diff(myPoints, axis=1)
    myPointsNew[1] =myPoints[np.argmin(diff)]
    myPointsNew[2] = myPoints[np.argmax(diff)] 
    return myPointsNew

pts1 = np.float32(reorder(cood))
w = 1000; h = 1000; m1 = 1000; m2 = 1000
pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [w, 0], [0, h], [w, h]])
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
result = cv2.warpPerspective(orig1, matrix, (m1, m2)) 
cv2_imshow(result)
```

I have also gone through [Microsoft's research](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Whiteboard-It.pdf), but not sure how to implement it.
I am not able to detect and perspective transform the board. It would be great if anyone of you can help me out. Also, do let me know if my question requires more details.

Comment: Did you tried color based approach?
Is it always the same board? Than you know width, height ratio. Then with some edge detection/Contour detection it should work

Comment: I haven't tried the color-based approach yet. But, the board may not be the same. We can't fix the coordinates. Is there a way to generalize it?

Comment: check this out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269147/how-to-extract-contours-from-hfs-segmented-image

Comment: The problem is the overexposed wall, so the wall is very white instead of his natural color gray. So you have to fix this first. I also saw that your image has a very poor quality. Sow texture based approach will be difficult. Maybe start looking for some model to detect the whiteboard in the image?

Comment: @Bamwani I have tried this. But, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get the 4 coordinates of the whiteboard. I have used adaptive thresholding to detect the edges rather than canny-edge detection, not sure whether the methodology is correct or not, but it is giving the required results.
Here's the code for the same.

```
import ...
img = cv2.imread("path-to-image")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 199, 5)
cv2_imshow(thresh)
```

[image: Threshold image]

```
# finding contours and applying perspective
try:
    copy = thresh.copy(); orig = img.copy()
    cnts = cv2.findContours(copy, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    area = -1; c1 = 0

    for c in cnts:
        epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(c,True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,epsilon,True)
        if len(approx) == 4 and area < cv2.contourArea(c):
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
            c1 = c; approx1 = approx

    warped = four_point_transform(orig, approx1.reshape(4, 2))
    cv2_imshow(warped)
except:
    print("Image cannot be transformed!!\n")

# four point transform
def order_points(pts):
    # https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/21/ordering-coordinates-clockwise-with-python-and-opencv/
    xSorted = pts[np.argsort(pts[:, 0]), :]
    leftMost = xSorted[:2, :]
    rightMost = xSorted[2:, :]
    leftMost = leftMost[np.argsort(leftMost[:, 1]), :]
    (tl, bl) = leftMost
    D = dist.cdist(tl[np.newaxis], rightMost, "euclidean")[0]
    (br, tr) = rightMost[np.argsort(D)[::-1], :]
    return np.array([tl, tr, br, bl], dtype="float32")

def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect  
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype = "float32")
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))
    return warped
```

Here's the warped image:
[image: Warped Image]